# Meaning of "I hope to understand what it means exactly"

Tags: meaning

> I hope to understand  exactly what it means.

What does this sentence mean?

1. I hope that I understand what it means exactly.
2. I hope that I'm going to understand what it means exactly.
3. 1 or 2 according to context.

I guess it could mean 1 or 2 according to context.
If there is something you cannot interpret from the sentence, could you give the reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb "hope" followed by the preposition "to" always implies future tense. Therefore the meaning is "I hope that I'm going to understand what it means exactly". That is to say that the understanding will be in the future. It cannot be "I hope that I understand what it means exactly." because that is in the present.